# First product save doesn't take during new admin session

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

For a new admin session, the first time I save a product, magento is very slow to save (30 seconds or longer) and goes back to products admin with no save to the product. After the first time attempting to save a product, other product saves happen quickly (1 second or so).

This only happens the first time during an admin session.

Magento 1.9.2 Lesti fpc m2e pro

Plenty of resources available for the php and mysql environment.